# I need help verifying the answers to these exercises [Velleman, Chapter 1.1, Q5]

Tags: logic, soft-question, notation, predicate-logic

I've begun to study Daniel Velleman's "How to Prove It" and I need to clarify a few things and ensure I've gotten the answers correct before I move on.

I've questions about quite a few of the exercises which I will be splitting up over multiple posts, I hope that isnt a problem.

---

## Exercise 1.1

### Question 5

> Let $P$ stand for the statement "I will buy the pants" and $S$ for the statement "I will buy the shirt". What English sentences are represented by the following expressions?
>
> **(a)** $\neg (P \wedge \neg S)$

---

#### (a) $\neg (P \wedge \neg S)$

The answer in the back of the book says that this statement means:

> I won't buy the pants without the shirt

I don't quite understand that, because the statement being negated here is $(P \wedge \neg S)$ and this statement to my understanding means "I will buy the pants but I will not buy the shirt". Thus the statement $\neg (P \wedge \neg S)= \neg P \wedge \neg \neg S$ is a negation of all this and should mean "I will not buy the pants but I will buy the shirt". I assume the double negation before the $S$ will result in a positive statement, in the same way if I said "I will **not not** eat ice cream", means I will eat ice cream.

**Can someone tell me where im going wrong here? Is my answer wrong?**

Comment: That f... De Morgan again !

Answer (score 1):

You say that $\neg(P \land \neg S) = \neg P \land \neg\neg S$. This is *not* true. You have to use [de Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which will give you
$$\neg(P \land \neg S) = \neg P \lor \neg\neg S = \neg P \lor S = P \rightarrow S,$$
meaning "If I buy the pants, then I also buy the shirt", or equivalently "I won't buy the pants without also buying the shirt".

---

A more intuitive way to think about it:

$\neg (P \land \neg S)$ means "it is not the case that both $P$ and not-$S$ are true", hence we must have that "either $P$ is false or not-$S$ is false", which is the same as $\neg P \lor \neg\neg S$. So far, this is just de Morgan's law. $\neg\neg S$ is, as you said, the same as $S$, so we get $\neg P \lor S$. This means "either I don't buy the pants, or I buy the shirt", which in particular means that if I do buy the paints, then I will also buy the shirt. This is the same as saying "I won't buy the pants without the shirt".

Comment: This is not introduced in the book at the stage where I am? Is there another way to tackle this?

Comment: @seeker I have tried to explain it another way.

Comment: You said: $\neg P \lor S$, this means "either I don't buy the pants, or I buy the shirt", which in particular means that if I do buy the pants, then I will also buy the shirt.  I'm sorry but I don't see how this follows?

Comment: @seeker either $\neg P$ or $S$ have to be true, so if I do buy the pants, then $P$ is true, which means $\neg P$ is false, and hence $S$ must be true, meaning I buy the shirt.

Comment: In essence, do I need to understand De Morgan's Law to understand this question? Because i'm quite confused right now..