# I need help verifying the answers to these exercises [Velleman, Chapter 1.1, Q6]

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I've begun to study Daniel Velleman's "How to Prove It" and I need to clarify a few things and ensure I've gotten the answers correct before I move on. Thank you.

---

### Question 6

> Let S stand for the statement "Steve is happy" and G for "George is happy". What English sentences are represented by the following expressions:
> **(a)** $(S\vee G) \wedge (\neg S \vee \neg G)$ 
> **(b)** $[S \vee (G \wedge \neg S)] \vee \neg G$ 
> **(c)** $S \vee [G \wedge (\neg S \vee \neg G)]$

---

#### (a) $(S\vee G) \wedge (\neg S \vee \neg G)$

This translates to:

Either Steve or George are happy and Steve or George are not happy.
**This seems very ill-worded to me, is there a better way to phrase this?**

#### (b) $[S \vee (G \wedge \neg S)] \vee \neg G$

This translates to:

Either Steve is happy or George is happy and Steve is not happy, OR George is not Happy.

#### (c) $S \vee [G \wedge (\neg S \vee \neg G)]$

This translates to:

Either Steve is happy OR George is happy and Steve is not happy or George is not happy.

**Again I don't really understand how to phrase this, the nested statements make things difficult for me, if someone could elucidate this for me it would be really appreciated**

Comment: a) George is only happy if Steve is also happy, and vice versa.

Comment: _This seems very ill-worded to me_ - that's because it's human language, which is not as strict in its definition as a mathematical operator. It explicitly has features that introduce uncertainty of definitions like sarcasm or irony. Language is open to ambiguity, math is not. (well, it tries not to be, at least)

Comment: I can offer a few comments, but do you still need answers for these 3?

Comment: @LePressentiment That would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: @seeker No problem. I forgot to ask: for 2 and 3, would you allow answers that used Rules of Replacement to simplify those statements? Without them, I fear that I also do not know how to improve prosaic descriptions of these long Logical Propositions.

Comment: @LePressentiment what is a rule of replacement? A substitution? Just answer it any way you see fit.

Comment: @seeker Yes, a substitution that simplifies an expression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_replacement. One of them is mentioned under [this other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1432617/53259). Do you wish to read more about this, before I try to answer, for efficiency?

Comment: @LePressentiment I'd say attempt to answer this how you feel comfortable but just bear in mind nothing too advanced as I've not got too far in my study of logic. Not to worry, I'll read up on the rules of replacement. Thanks.

Comment: @seeker May I postpone my offer for efficiency, because may I please suggest to try reading Chapters 7.1 to 7.4 inclusive of *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley first?  This is what I am doing now; I am also studying logic too.

Comment: @LePressentiment is it possible we could chat some time tomorrow? It's just that it is a little late over here. Furthermore I want to refresh my memory and read over the questions I asked (as they were asked a while ago). Thank you for your offer of help.

Comment: @seeker You are welcome. Sure. Just message me. Good night!

Comment: @LePressentiment thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

a) at least one of the two is happy and at least one of the two is not, therefore one is happy and the other is not.